# Imprimir informações de arraylist na tela

Tags: java, arraylist, printf, print

Eu tenho uma `ArrayList` mas não estou conseguindo imprimir os dados na tela.

Segue classe:

```
public class Cachorro {

    private String Raca;
    private String cor;
    private String nome;
    private String nome_dono;
    private int idade;


    public Cachorro(String Raca,String cor,String nome,String nome_dono, int idade){

        this.Raca = Raca;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.nome =nome;
        this.nome_dono = nome_dono;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public String getRaca() {
        return Raca;
    }
    public void setRaca(String raca) {
        Raca = raca;
    }
    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }
    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getNome_dono() {
        return nome_dono;
    }
    public void setNome_dono(String nome_dono) {
        this.nome_dono = nome_dono;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }


    public  String toString(){
        return "Nome Cao:" +getNome()+"\nCor:" +getCor()+
                "\nRaca:"+getRaca()+"\nNome dono:"+ getNome_dono()+"\nIdade:"+getIdade();
    }


}
```

Classe principal:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> dog =  new ArrayList<>();

        Cachorro cc = new Cachorro("rotweiller","preto","Flora","Cesar",8);

        dog.add(cc);
        System.out.println(dog);

    }

}
```

Comment: Cesar como dog é uma lista você precisa informar qual é a posição dela que vc quer imprimir por exemplo você poderia fazer assim System.out.println(dog.get(1).getPropriedade());

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tem alguns erros. Primeiro precisa criar uma lista de `Cachorros` e não de `Strings`. Depois precisa usar um `foreach` para varrer toda a lista. Mudei o nome da variável da lista porque uma lista tem vários cachorro**s** e não apenas um. Note que não precisa chamar o `toString()`, ele é chamado pelo `println()`. Dei uma organizada também.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Cachorro {
    private String Raca;
    private String cor;
    private String nome;
    private String nome_dono;
    private int idade;

    public Cachorro(String Raca,String cor,String nome,String nome_dono, int idade){
        this.Raca = Raca;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.nome =nome;
        this.nome_dono = nome_dono;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public String getRaca() {
        return Raca;
    }
    public void setRaca(String raca) {
        Raca = raca;
    }
    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }
    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getNome_dono() {
        return nome_dono;
    }
    public void setNome_dono(String nome_dono) {
        this.nome_dono = nome_dono;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public  String toString() {
        return "Nome Cao:" + getNome() + "\nCor: " + getCor() +
                "\nRaca: " + getRaca()  +"\nNome dono: " + getNome_dono() + "\nIdade: " + getIdade();
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cachorro> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        dogs.add(new Cachorro("rotweiller", "preto", "Flora", "Cesar", 8));
        for (Cachorro dog : dogs) System.out.println(dog);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EGzkE4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/eewhtjft-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/PrintItems2.java).

Comment: biggown Obrigado pela ajuda segui sua dica e já está funcionando perfeito. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram :)

Answer (score 7):

Tem várias coisas erradas aí.

Primeiro que esse código nem deve compilar já que nessa linha `List<String> dog =  new ArrayList<>();` é instanciada uma lista de `String` e na linha abaixo tenta adicionar um objeto do tipo `Cachorro` nela.

Veja um exemplo do código corrigido

**Obs.:** Perceba que eu troquei os nomes das variáveis. É sempre uma boa ideia usar nomes descritivos para as variáveis, deixa o código muito mais legível.

```
List<Cachorro> listaCachorros = new ArrayList<>();
Cachorro cachorro = new Cachorro("rotweiller","preto","Flora","Cesar",8);

listaCachorros.add(cachorro);

// imprimir os dados do objeto 'cachorro' (adicionado na lista)
System.out.println(cachorro.ToString());

// imprimir os dados de todos os objetos da lista    
for(Cachorro c : listaCachorros)
{
    System.out.println(c.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Na classe principal, a lista que você iniciou está com String, não seria uma lista de Cachorro?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Cachorro> dog = new ArrayList<>();

    Cachorro cc = new Cachorro("rotweiller", "preto", "Flora", "Cesar", 8);

    dog.add(cc);
    System.out.println(dog);
}
```

Comment: Desculpa galera, sou novo, obrigado pela ajuda @j

Comment: Tranquilo. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]

Answer (score 1):

Temos um problema neste código!

Sua lista é de `String` e você está tentando adicionar `Cachorro`

Há duas opções ( que irá imprimir o mesmo conteúdo  )

Transformar a Lista em uma Lista de Cachorro:

```
 List<Cachorro> dog =  new ArrayList<>();
```

Ou adicionar a `String` do `Cachorro` na lista:

```
dog.add(cc.toString());
```

Comment: Mesmo resultado? Tem certeza?

Comment: Sim! Se eu imprimir uma lista de Cachorro ele não vai chamar o **toString()**?

Comment: Vai. E depois se ele quiser usar os objetos? Faz o quê?

Comment: Então, levei em consideração o contexto da  pergunta: **"Eu tenho uma arraylist mas nao estou conseguindo imprimir os dados na tela"**

Comment: Beleza. Que bom que tem ciência que são coisas diferentes, embora iguais pro mesmo contexto. Só quis te alertar que não é a mesma coisa num geral. Não acho que a resposta mereça upvote, mas também não vou votar negativo pq está certa (embora possa confundir o leitor)

Comment: @jbueno , Alterei a resposta pra ficar mais clara!  ( Pensei que vc já tinha negativado! hahaha ) Assim, acho complicado  (em casos específicos como este) "sugerir" que está errado criar uma lista de Cachorro e não de String, pois não temos o contexto geral do que ele está fazendo! Tento sempre levar em consideração o contexto da pergunta (mesmo que pra mim, pareça estranho )