# Qual biblioteca de string que eu posso usar?

Tags: java, string

Estou refatorando um código que usa o pluggin do eclipse mas quero transforma-lo para java puro. 
A ideia é transformar a String em algo com esse estilo:

```
Person@182f0db
[
   name=John Doe
   age=33
   smoker=false
]
```

O código atual está usando as bibliotecas `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder` e  `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle`:

```
ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
```

Qual a biblioteca de java puro que consigo fazer exatamente isso? Eu sei que tem um `StringBuilder`porém não sei um método que faça essa mesma ação.

Comment: O StringBuilder não fará nada do que procura, ele é utilizado para concatenar strings. É estranho você querer que uma biblioteca faça essa solução para você. Não seria mais fácil sobreescrever o `@toString()`?

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata): [Dúvidas sobre o método toString() da classe Object
Faça uma pergunta
votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10893/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Imprimir informações de arraylist na tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170712/28595) e [Como faço para exibir o que está dentro da lista?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165731/28595)

Answer (score 1):

Como você está usando `this` na chamada a `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);`, suponho que esta seja justamente a implementação do método toString() da classe Person.

Você pode construir a String "na mão" desse jeito:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new String(
        this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
            + "\n["
            + "\n  name=" + name
            + "\n  age=" + age
            + "\n  smoker=" + smoker
            + "\n]");
}
```

A questão é:  por que você iria querer fazer isso?

ToStringBuilder não é de um "plugin do eclipse": é uma biblioteca adicionada ao projeto, mas especificamente o commons-lang3, do Apache. Não há nada demais em usar bibliotecas avulsas nos seus projetos. Você não irá muito longe com uma aplicação se quiser fazer tudo "na mão", aliás, é não recomendável reinventar a roda.